# posting data not showing same format in server side using Restkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, restkit

i have dictionary of data in my hand.i want to post this Using Restkit.

```
""ADDRESS{ major = 604; minor = 37940; uuid = "xxxxxx"; }, {major = 1; minor = 4541; uuid = "xxxxx"; },{ major = 20310; minor = 48417; uuid = "xxxx";},
```

i passed this data using RestKit but in the server side it getting like this

```
{ "ADDRESS": [ {"major": "604" }, { "minor": "37940" }, { "uuid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" },
```

is any way to get same data format in server side also.Thank you in advance

Comment: Try adding **nil** at the end of your dictionary object when you initializing them
 { major = 604; minor = 37940; uuid = "xxxxxx";nil }

Comment: @MahbubAhmed  

    self.beaconsDictionary = @{@"uuid" :[beacon.proximityUUID UUIDString],
                                                            @"major":beacon.major,
                                   @"minor":beacon.minor};
                  [self.beaconListArray addObject:self.beaconsDictionary];
            
                  }
My code is this for adding.where i want to add

Comment: Try this @{@"uuid" :[beacon.proximityUUID UUIDString], @"major":beacon.major, @"minor":beacon.minor,nil}; it might help